# How to pass all Python's traffics through a http proxy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to pass all Python's traffics through a http proxy server, I checked urlib2 and requests packages for instance, they can be configured to use proxies but how could I use something like a system-wide proxy for Python to proxy all the data out?

Comment: What do you mean by system-wide proxy and how do you configure it? If there is one, you should extract it and set it in urllib2.

Comment: I mean, I don't want to use a proxy for just a particular Python library(like requests), instead I want to pass all traffics originating from Python process running my script through a proxy.

Comment: I think you are trying to approach this from a wrong direction. If you need something like "system wide proxy" you should try solve this issue on network level. I don't think there are system wide config files for urlib or requests libraries.

Comment: What kind of script? I am assuming you have a shell script that starts few python processes and you want them to use the proxy.

Answer (score 82):

**Linux system** first export the environment variables like this

```
$ export http_proxy="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"

$ export https_proxy="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"
```

or in the script that you want to pass through the proxy

```
import os

proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

#your code goes here.............
```

then run python script

```
$ python my_script.py
```

**UPDATE**

And also you can use [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks)
With this tool you can redirect silently all your TCP connections to a PROXY with or without authentication. But you have to be carefull because it's for all connections not only for the python.

**Windows systems** you can use tools like [freecap](http://www.freecap.ru/), [proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/), [proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com/), and configure to run behind the python executable

Comment: @efirvida Its not working in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676514/how-to-resolve-proxy-error-in-reading-writing-to-hdfs-using-python

I came across your answer after I posted this question. I tried exporting the proxies like you say here, and then os.environ... But the error persists.

Comment: faced with     encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @zhilevan, i dont know about that error, but maybe try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482272/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-python-2-to-3

Comment: Just tried and the process stuck after assigning this to the four environment variables. The log is not coming out as well.

Comment: You're a gem. Solved an issue I was trying to solve since yesterday. Thank you!!

Comment: To use the SOCKS Protocol, replace `http` or `https` with the `socks4` or `socks5` as in `socks4://127.0.0.1:8080`.

Comment: Cypher's comment worked for me! It is essentially the same as doing `curl --socks5 localhost:8080` now

Answer (score 6):

Admittedly, this isn't exactly what you are looking for, but if you know the programmatic source of all your network traffic in your python code, you can do this proxy wrapping in the code itself.  A pure python solution is suggested using the `PySocks` module in the following link:

https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/issues/22

```
import httplib2
# detect presense of proxy and use env varibles if they exist
pi = httplib2.proxy_info_from_environment()
if pi:
    import socks
    socks.setdefaultproxy(pi.proxy_type, pi.proxy_host, pi.proxy_port)
    socks.wrapmodule(httplib2)    

# now all calls through httplib2 should use the proxy settings
httplib2.Http()
```

Now every call made using `httplib2` will use those proxy settings.  You should be able to wrap any networking module that uses sockets to use this proxy.

https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

They mention there that this isn't recommended, but it seems to be working fine for me.