# Passing all Python's traffic through proxy using PyCharm

Tags: python, proxy, pycharm, global

I am working in a corporate environment with a proxy (with user/passs). I use PyCharm on a Windows machine and Python 3.6.

Based on this post:
[How to pass all Python's traffics through a http proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639742/how-to-pass-all-pythons-traffics-through-a-http-proxy) I managed to write my python script that connects to the web.

Unfortunately I had to reinstall Pycharm and create a new python project. Now I run the same script that connects to the web but receive the following error message (simply trying to connect to google.com):

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))
```

This is my code:

```
import os

proxy = 'http://user:password@proxyname:port'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
print(r.text)
```

If I change the line

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

to this:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com', verify=False)
```

it works but I receive the warning:

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.
```

Executing the code on another machine without proxy This issue doesn't appear at all.

I added google's certificate in PyCharm's settings (Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates) and selected "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically". But nothing changes, same error messages.

Is there any further settings I can do in PyCharm/Python to solve that issue?

Comment: You may want to try the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036374/how-to-specify-pip-options-in-pycharm-for-installing-from-requirements-txt/53638146#53638146