# How to specify pip options in PyCharm for installing from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

To install Python packages from behind a corporate proxy, it is sometimes necessary to add options to `pip`, such as `--proxy` or `--cert`.

How to specify a proxy in PyCharm is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42363175/2311167) and how to add *any* option to the `pip` call is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065175/2311167).

The latter would allow me to add the required `--cert` option. Unfortunately, this works only when installing a package manually and does not cover the case where I have a `requirements.txt` file and want PyCharm to automatically install the packages listed. This results in this error:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)': /simple/robotframework/

Which means that I need to add something to the underlying `pip` call (`--cert` in my case).

**Question:** How can I specify `pip` options that will be used by PyCharm for automatic installation of the packages specified in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: No way to do this at the moment, feel free to file an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the CA cert inserted by your corporate firewall and install it to pip's keystore. Below is the process I used, but I'm sure those more adept at cert formats/manipulation can improve it:

> PLEASE NOTE: Pip's cacerts.pem file will be overwritten whenever pip
>   is upgraded, so the company cert will need to be re-inserted.

**Step 1**. Identify the correct keystore. If you are using a virtual environment, the location of the keystore used by pip when it is activated should be `C:\PATH\TO\VENV\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem`

NOTE: Unlike most keystores that I have dealt with (mostly while trying to get JetBrains products to work behind corpo firewalls), this one is plain text. *More on this in Step 3*.

**Step 2**. Download the cert. Using Firefox (there are many ways to do this), go to the URL that precedes the error (something like https://pypi.org/simple/, or https://pypi.python.org/simple/). Click on the Lock > Show connection details > More information. On Page Info window, Click View Certificate > Details Tab. Export the top-level cert as .crt/.pem. Click back to the General tab, it may be needed in Step 3.

**Step 3**. Normally, you could just use a keytool command like `keytool -import -alias key-alias -file "C:\path\to\exported\key.der" -keystore "C:\Path\to\keystore\.PyCharm2018.3\system\tasks\cacerts"`,but when you do, you get the following *keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format: null*. It turns out you can just copy the plain text cert exported in Step 2 directly into the keystore.

You don't need to include any header information, just from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- to -----END CERTIFICATE-----. However, it may be beneficial in the future if someone (you) has to look at this keystore again, so you can copy it from the General Tab mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a (py)charm! However, I did not need step 3: I exported the corporate CA as PEM, then simply used a text editor to add it to cacert.pem located in step 1.

Comment: One litte observation: upgrading pip resets cacert.pem. So, after upgrading pip, one has to put back the corporate CA cert into cacert.pem.

Comment: PyCharm's keystore seems not be required for installing Python packages, but for giving the IDE itself trust to web sites. Moreover Step 3 did not work for me, because `keytool` insists on a password for the store and PyCharm's store does not have a password (but is DER, not PEM). PyCharm's Settings->Tools->Server Certificates is a convenient means to populate that store. The easiest way to get rid of all proxy cert issues is to tick "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" there. That allowed me to install plugins from behind the firewall (but that was not the original question).

Comment: For some reason, "Accepting non-trusted certificates" in PyCharm's settings has not worked for me. The keytool command was not expected to work, but the wording for Step 3 can probably be improved.