# Use Python Driver to connect to a Neo4J behind a wepproxy

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

I would like to use the neo4j-python driver to connect to a remote neo4j enterprise instance (hosted on azure). My development machine is unfortunatly (due to corporate policy) behind a proxy. In other libraries and also in the neo4j desktop application I can specify a proxy. I didn't find any documentation on how to configure a proxy for the neo4j python driver. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I tried to solve it using environmental variables for now, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446368/passing-all-pythons-traffic-through-proxy-using-pycharm. 
Doesn't work...Problem is I guess, that the driver is not using http?

Comment: Can you use ssh to forward the bolt port?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, as ssh is blocked by the proxy

Comment: Hmm, then I think this is not a "neo4j question" more a question for your your it folks, maybe you need a jump box on azure?

Comment: But I guess this means there is no configuration available for the python driver? Other database drivers have specifically available the option to configure proxy settings.