# How to resolve proxy error in reading & writing to HDFS using Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, authentication, proxy, kerberos

I have a HDFS to which I want to read and write using a Python script.

```
import requests
import json
import os
import kerberos
import sys

node = os.getenv("namenode").split(",")
print (node)

local_file_path = sys.argv[1]
remote_file_path = sys.argv[2]
read_or_write = sys.argv[3]
print (local_file_path,remote_file_path)

def check_node_status(node):
    for name in node:
        print (name)
        request = requests.get("%s/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus"%name,
                               verify=False).json()
        status = request["beans"][0]["State"]
        if status =="active":
            nnhost = request["beans"][0]["HostAndPort"]
            splitaddr = nnhost.split(":")
            nnaddress = splitaddr[0]
            print(nnaddress)
            break
    return status,name,nnaddress

def kerberos_auth(nnaddress):
    __, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTP@%s"%nnaddress)
    kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
    negotiate_details = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(krb_context)
    headers = {"Authorization": "Negotiate " + negotiate_details,
                "Content-Type":"application/binary"}
    return headers

def kerberos_hdfs_upload(status,name,headers):
    print("running upload function")
    if status =="active":
        print("if function")
        data=open('%s'%local_file_path, 'rb').read()
        write_req = requests.put("%s/webhdfs/v1%s?op=CREATE&overwrite=true"%(name,remote_file_path),
                                 headers=headers,
                                 verify=False, 
                                 allow_redirects=True,
                                 data=data)
        print(write_req.text)

def kerberos_hdfs_read(status,name,headers):
    if status == "active":
        read = requests.get("%s/webhdfs/v1%s?op=OPEN"%(name,remote_file_path),
                            headers=headers,
                            verify=False,
                            allow_redirects=True)

        if read.status_code == 200:
            data=open('%s'%local_file_path, 'wb')
            data.write(read.content)
            data.close()
        else : 
            print(read.content)


status, name, nnaddress= check_node_status(node)
headers = kerberos_auth(nnaddress)
if read_or_write == "write":
    kerberos_hdfs_upload(status,name,headers)
elif read_or_write == "read":
    print("fun")
    kerberos_hdfs_read(status,name,headers)
```

The code works on my own machine which is not behind any proxy. But when running it in the office machine, which is behind a proxy, it is giving the following proxy error:

```
$ python3 python_hdfs.py ./1.png /user/testuser/2018-02-07_1.png write
['https://<servername>:50470', 'https:// <servername>:50470']
./1.png /user/testuser/2018-02-07_1.png
https://<servername>:50470
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 555, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 753, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 230, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 832, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 504 Unknown Host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 273, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<servername>', port=50470): Max retries exceeded with url: /jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 504 Unknown Host',)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_hdfs.py", line 68, in <module>
    status, name, nnaddress= check_node_status(node)
  File "python_hdfs.py", line 23, in check_node_status
    verify=False).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<server_name>', port=50470): Max retries exceeded with url: /jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 504 Unknown Host',)))
```

I tried giving proxy info in the code, like so:

```
proxies = {
"http": "<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_IP>:<proxy_port>",
"https": "<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_IP>:<proxy_port>",
}

node = os.getenv("namenode").split(",")
print (node)
local_file_path = sys.argv[1]
remote_file_path = sys.argv[2]
print (local_file_path,remote_file_path)


local_file_path = sys.argv[1]
remote_file_path = sys.argv[2]
read_or_write = sys.argv[3]
print (local_file_path,remote_file_path)

def check_node_status(node):
        for name in node:
                print (name)
                request = requests.get("%s/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus"%name,proxies=proxies,
                                                           verify=False).json()
                status = request["beans"][0]["State"]
                if status =="active":
                        nnhost = request["beans"][0]["HostAndPort"]
                        splitaddr = nnhost.split(":")
                        nnaddress = splitaddr[0]
                        print(nnaddress)
                        break
        return status,name,nnaddress
### Rest of the code is the same
```

Now it is giving the following error:

```
$ python3 python_hdfs.py ./1.png /user/testuser/2018-02-07_1.png write
['https://<servername>:50470', 'https:// <servername>:50470']
./1.png /user/testuser/2018-02-07_1.png
https://<servername>:50470
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_hdfs.py", line 73, in <module>
    status, name, nnaddress= check_node_status(node)
  File "python_hdfs.py", line 28, in check_node_status
    verify=False).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 343, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 254, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 160, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 281, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 232, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme <proxy_username>
```

So, my question is, do I need to set up the proxy in kerberos for it to be working? If so, how? I am not too familiar with kerberos. I run `kinit` before running the python code, in order to enter into the kerberos realm, which runs fine and connects to the appropriate HDFS servers without the proxy. So I don't know why this error occurs when reading or writing to the same HDFS servers. Any help is appreciated.

I also have the proxy set up in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` like so:

```
Acquire::http::proxy  "http://<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_IP>:<proxy_port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy_username>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_IP>:<proxy_port>/";
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$ export http_proxy="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"

$ export https_proxy="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>"

import os

proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

#rest of the code is same
```

But the error persists.

**UPDATE:** I have also tried the following.

1. Somebody suggested that we already have a proxy set up in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to connect to the web. But maybe we don't need proxy to connect to the HDFS. So, try commenting the proxies in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, and run the python script again. I did that.

   $ env | grep proxy
   http_proxy=http://hfli:Test6969@192.168.44.217:8080
   https_proxy=https://hfli:Test6969@192.168.44.217:8080
   $ unset http_proxy
   $ unset https_proxy
   $ env | grep proxy
   $

And ran the python script again - (i) without defining proxies in the python script, and also (ii) with the proxies defined in the python script. I got the same original proxy error in both cases.

2. I found the following Java program that supposedly gives access to run Java programs on the HDFS:

   import com.sun.security.auth.callback.TextCallbackHandler;
   import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
   import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
   import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import javax.security.auth.Subject;
   import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;

   import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
   import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

   public class HDFS_RW_Secure 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
       {
           System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/tmp/sc3_temp/hadoop_kdc.txt");
           System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/tmp/sc3_temp/hadoop_krb.txt");
           Configuration hadoopConf= new Configuration();
           //this example use password login, you can change to use Keytab login
           LoginContext lc;
           Subject subject;
           lc = new LoginContext("JaasSample", new TextCallbackHandler());
           lc.login();
           System.out.println("login");

   ```
       subject = lc.getSubject();
       UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hadoopConf);
       UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getUGIFromSubject(subject);
       UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(ugi); 

       Path pt=new Path("hdfs://edhcluster"+args[0]);

       FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf);

       //write
       FSDataOutputStream fin = fs.create(pt);
       fin.writeUTF("Hello!");
       fin.close();

       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
       String line;
       line=br.readLine();
       while (line != null)
       {
              System.out.println(line);
              line=br.readLine();
       }
       fs.close();
       System.out.println("This is the end.");
   ```

   }
   }

We need to take its jar file, `HDFS.jar`, and run the following shell script to enable Java programs to be run on the HDFS.

```
nano run.sh
# contents of the run.sh file:
/tmp/sc3_temp/jre1.8.0_161/bin/java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/sc3_temp/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -jar /tmp/sc3_temp/HDFS.jar $1
```

So, I can run this shell script with `/user/testuser` as the argument to give it access to run Java programs in the HDFS:

```
./run.sh /user/testuser/test2
```

which gives the following output:

```
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache false useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Kerberos username [testuser]: testuser
Kerberos password for testuser: 
        [Krb5LoginModule] user entered username: testuser

principal is testuser@KRB.REALM
Commit Succeeded 

login
2018-02-08 14:09:30,020 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Hello!
This is the end.
```

So, that's working I suppose. But how do I write an equivalent shell script to run Python codes?

Comment: Before use the python script, try exporting the env variables, then use wget or curl, to see if you can connect. I prefer `pycurl` over request. Another solution can be using `redsocks` https://github.com/darkk/redsocks

Comment: @efirvida Interesting. When I do wget, I get this error: `Connecting to <proxy_server>:<proxy_port>... connected. Proxy tunnelling failed: Unknown HostUnable to establish SSL connection`. Why is it still connecting to proxy server when I have disabled it? In fact, how does it even know the IP of the proxy server, as I have removed its definition from all places (`~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/environment` and `Settings -> Network -> Proxy -> None')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out, I was looking in the wrong place. It seems the user account was set up wrongly. I tried to do something simpler, like downloading a webpage into the server. And I noticed that it was downloading the page, but had no permissions to fix it. So I explored a bit more and found that when the user account was created, it was not assigned proper ownership. So, once I assigned the proper owner to the user account, the proxy error was gone. (Sigh, so much time wasted.)

I have written about it in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700551/5305512).