# Is there a way to enable tor as system proxy settings through Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, proxy, tor

I am working on a project which requires accessing some websites with and without tor enabled, and record the content differences.
I am working on deepin (which is a linux based debian distro), and using Python 2.7 to accomplish the task. The problem is that I have to manually enable/disable tor, and change the system proxy settings every time I run the script. Now, I am aware that I can issue a shell command from Python itself to enable tor (service tor start), but I cannot figure out how to enable/disable the system proxy settings from Python.

I have already tried [this](https://github.com/nityanandagohain/proxy_configuration), but no luck.

Comment: *debian based linux distro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass all Python's traffics through a http proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31639742/608639), [How to unset the 'http_proxy' environment variable in Python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425442), etc.

Comment: it is not a duplicate to that question. That question deals with HTTP proxy. Tor is a SOCKS proxy, that the question does not address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the thing working, posting here in case someone else has the same problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from splinter import Browser
proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 9050
proxy_settings = {"network.proxy.type":0,
    "network.proxy.socks": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.socks_port": proxyPort
}
browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)
driver = browser.driver
driver.get('https://whatismyip.com')
```

changing network.proxy.type to 1 resets the proxy settings. Solution found [here](http://www.thedurkweb.com/automated-anonymous-interactions-with-websites-using-python-and-tor/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.system` to set the desired proxy like this.

```
import os
os.system("export http_proxy="http://username:Password@Proxy_IP:Port/")
```

To unset, simply use

```
os.system("unset http_proxy")
```

**EDIT**

Tor uses SOCKS proxy. For socks proxy, use

```
os.system("export socks_proxy="socks://username:Password@Proxy_IP:Port/")
```

Comment: The problem is, Tor is not an HTTP proxy, its rather a SOCKS proxy. I tried modifying your code to "socks_proxy" instead of "http_proxy", and then tried used requests.session() to get my IP from http://httpbin.org/ip, but the returned IP was the same as my original IP address, which means the request did not go through tor. I used: os.system("export socks_proxy=\"http://:@127.0.0.1:9050/\"")

Comment: @KhizarAmin I am updating my answer for socks proxy. What u tried for socks is partially correct. Please see the edit in answer for the correct command.