# Configure proxy with python

Tags: python, proxy, api

I am looking to use a public API running on a distant server from within my company. For security reasons, I am supposed to redirect all the traffic via the company's PROXY. Does anyone know how to do this in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass all Python's traffics through a http proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639742/how-to-pass-all-pythons-traffics-through-a-http-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

Directly in python you can do :

`os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = http://proxy.host.com:8080`.

Or as it has been mentioned before launching by @hardillb on a terminal :

`export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.host.com:8080`

Comment: Thanks man, I searched for this for hours :D although it should be:
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://proxy.host.com:8080" 
with quotes around the proxy

Comment: if i have to assign multiple address to no_proxy  will it be like:
os.environ["no_proxy"] = "add1","add2","localhost","127.0.0.1"
I m not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Set the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before starting your python script

e.g. `export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.host.com:8080`